# JQUERY Automatic Carousel

Tags: jquery, css, carousel

I m trying to use the following script for the carousel. But two mistakes are showing up and I can t figure it out whats the issue. First the images are cut in the end as you can see and then the last image jumps incorrectly. I ll very much appreciate ur help. Best!  Victoria.

http://vtwg.eu/PLANTA/prueba.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following to your CSS:

```
.ct {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

This will fix part of the problem.

Furthermore, the 5th `li` element has a black image. Not sure if that is intentional.

Finally, the 3rd `li` element has a < character which should be deleted.

Comment: Not OP, but I can confirm that this solves the issue.  Here's a demo implementing Gerard's changes: https://jsfiddle.net/55dynpbv/.  (I've removed the relatively linked `nnn.jpg` images.)  Only thing I have to add on top of those changes is that jQuery version `1.12.4` is really *really* old.  Unless this version is being used because of some production dependency, I'd highly recommend using a more recent version.

Comment: @Gerard this solution works perfectly thanks a lot!